# Is there a way to query / access list of available transaction classes in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can we query the business network to show a list of transaction classes? and knowing transaction class name, can we query the required parameters to pass when invoking it?

Eg: BusinessNetworkA consist of 3 Transaction classes {TradeApples, BuyCar, RentHouse}

- TradeApples requires price per kg as parameter
- BuyCar requires Car VIN and price as parameters
- Rent requires House Number and price as parameters

Comment: hi, yes, either through the APIs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/common-businessnetworkdefinition#getintrospector eg -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-common/test/businessnetworkdefinition.js#L223 or (if using the REST server), through Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily done:

```
    query getCupData { 
         description: "particular batch" 
         statement: 
                SELECT org.ibm.coffee.cupCoffee
                   WHERE (cupId == _$CupId ) 
}
```

Use TradeApple in place of cupCoffe and pricePerKg in place of cupId and _$CupId would be input variable and you can have any type of query between your variable.

PS: This should go in a separate file named **queries.qry** ***(Name is Important should be same)***